# Can I activate 2 Lucky-Eggs at the same time? If yes, is it working like x4 XP or what?

Tags: pokemon-go

I read that Lucky Egg gives you double XP for 30 mins. I just want to know if it's possible to activate 2 Lucky Eggs at the same time. If yes, what is its effect? Do you gain x4 XP or waste the second one?

Comment: The only thing that stacks is different types of modules (helpers if you will) you can stack a lucky egg, a incense, and a lure module at the same time, but you can't double stack any of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Lucky eggs (I guess you're talking about these) won't stack. Actually you can't even use a second Lucky egg after using the first, since you'll get the "You've already applied this type of enhancement." message (thanks @jdero for the info)

Comment: This is somewhat misleading. It's impossible to use two Lucky Eggs at the same time. -> "You've already applied this type of enhancement."

Comment: @jdero Thanks for the info, somehow I managed to use two at the same time, probably due to a server glitch. I've updated the answer